# Cannot read property 'insertId' of undefined in NodeJS with MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await, promise, node-mysql

I'm trying to fetch an insertId from an async await MySQL query in NodeJS. I've go the following code;

```
    row_a = await db.query( 'INSERT INTO audioposts (title,userid,opid) VALUES (?,?,? )', [title,userid,opid]);   
    
    var newid = row_a[0].insertId;
```

But I'm getting this error;

```
  Cannot read property 'insertId' of undefined
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: What is the value of row_a after the query is run?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can just do this;

```
  var newid = row_a.insertId;
```